# Bind field on cascade angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms, data-binding, cascadingdropdown

I must do a post request for form with angular js.. Almost everything seems to work.. in fact, all the field of the form are sent to the server correctly... except one! This field is particular..
I explain... I have a dropDownList that is filled on the base of the selected radio button...

I don't manage to post the radio button when i post the form...

Here the form:

```
<table class="three_column" ng-controller="PresentaUnAmicoController">
    <tr>
        <td class="text_centered">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in pianiTariffari" style="display:inline-block; margin:0 5px;">
                <input id="rb{{ value.TipoCliente }}" name="TipoCliente" type="radio" ng-model="$parent.TipoCliente" ng-value="value" required /><label for = "rb{{ value.TipoCliente }}">{{ value.TipoCliente }}</label>
            </div> //The radio button does not work
        </td>
        <td>
            <select ng-options="item as item.Name for item in TipoCliente.TariffPlans" ng-model="request.PianoTariffario"></select> //This work
        </td>
   </tr>
```

I think the problem is that the ng-model is `$parent.TipoCliente` and not `request.TipoCliente`... but If I use `request.TipoCliente` when I select the radio button, the dropDownList is not filled.

How can I solve the problem? Do you need more details?

EDIT: Here the object I want to post...
Every property is well filled except "TipoCliente"

```
public class PresentaUnAmicoRequest
{
    public string TipoCliente { get; set; }
    public TariffPlan PianoTariffario { get; set; }
    public string PresentatoreCodiceCliente { get; set; }
    public string PresentatoreNomeCognome { get; set; }
    public string PresentatoreEmail { get; set; }
    public string AmicoNomeCognome { get; set; }
    public string AmicoEmail { get; set; }
    public string Messaggio { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

As you can see I have the dropdown and the textarea in my `request` object but there is not the radio button value...

Comment: What is item object? do you want to post just the id or something right? Confused issue is with posting the dropdown or radio?

Comment: I have edited the post. To me it is the same to post the id or a complex object... The problem, is posting the radio button

Comment: I have solved adding `ng-change="request.TipoCliente=value.TipoCliente"` to the radio button, but I don't really like this solution.. I think that I am wrong in something, I think this is not the right way to do...